# Asynchronous execution of vbscript inside HTA file

Tags: html, asynchronous, vbscript, hta

I have a script inside the HEAD of an HTA file which executes as soon as the file is run. The script will retrieve some information from the network then update the HTML body.

The HTML will not display until the script has finished executing, I'm looking for a way to make the script run in an Asynchronous way.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Put the script just before the closing `body` tag?

Comment: I couldn't find a way so i used the OnLoad and SetTimeout to allow the Page to load before the Script runs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this :

```
<script src="demo_async.js" async></script>
```

Async tells the page not to stop loading while downloading a particular script . Find more info here :

https://css-tricks.com/async-attribute-scripts-bottom/